# for /f "tokens=4" %%A in ('route print ^| findstr "0.0.0.0"') выдает больше одной строки

Tags: cmd, поиск

[image: route print]

`for /f "tokens=4" %%A in ('route print ^| findstr "0.0.0.0"') do echo %%A` выдает несколько строк, хотя в фильтре указано `0.0.0.0` и есть только одна строчка с данным вхождением.

[image: output]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В теме вопроса `^|`, а на скриншоте просто `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что просишь, то тебе и находят:

24**0.0.0.0**

Правильно: findstr "\<0.0.0.0"

Comment: Благодарю, теперь работает как нужно